# Refresh DataContext in LINQPad

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontext, linqpad

Hi there I am struggling to deal with the following situation using LINQPad

```
While(1 = 1) 
{ 

    MyEntity _me = MyEntities.FirstOrDefault(); 

    foreach(ChildEntity ce in MyEntity.ChildEntities) 
    { 
            Console.WriteLine(ce.Value); 
    } 

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000); 
}
```

Where MyEntity (and the ChildEntities collection) is an automatically created LINQ to SQL class.  The rows in the underlying database may change independently of this script and I would like the ChildEntities collection to refresh from the database on each iteration of the While Loop.  It currently does not.

This does not work

```
this.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, _me);
```

nor does

```
this.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, _me.ChildEntities);
```

is there anyway that I can close and re-open the LINQPad DataContext  (I am a premium subscriber)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in LINQ-to-SQL.

You can re-initialize the LINQPad DataContext by instantiating it explicitly:

```
while(1 = 1) 
{     
    var freshDC = new TypedDataContext();
    var me = freshDC.MyEntities.FirstOrDefault(); 
    ...
}
```